# Size of ArrayList modified by parallel stream

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, stream

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0,100).parallel().forEach(data::add);
System.out.println(data.size());
```

Why above code does not always print 100? What happens to these numbers that are not counted when printed result is for example 94?
I know that I can use forEachOrdered(), CopyOnWriteArrayList or Collections.synchronizedList(). But what exactly happens with missing 6 elements in the above example?
Does each thread have its own copy of ArrayList and then these are somehow combined?

Comment: Use `forEachOrdered` if you want a garantee that all elements are added to your list.

Comment: Note that you'd be fine if you wrote `data = IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel().collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new))`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

When two thread try to increment that counter simultaneously, one of them overwrite result of other.

Try to do it with threadsafe collection an you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<E>` is not synchronized / thread-safe, that's why.

You can use synchronized list, as:

```java
List<Integer> data = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
IntStream.range(0,100).parallel().forEach(data::add);
System.out.println(data.size());
```

or [forEachOrdered](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered(java.util.function.Consumer)), as:

```java
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0,100).parallel().forEachOrdered(data::add);
System.out.println(data.size());
```

as it's documentations says, that:

> the action may be performed in whatever thread the library chooses.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use synchronizedCollection(). [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized-collections) will help you about that.

Comment: Answer should be self-contained. If you have the time, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68911519/edit) and include a brief summary of why `synchronizedCollection` can solve OP's issues. In case the blog is removed, future developer can still rely on your answer. Links are only used for support of what actually exists in answer.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will edit when i m available